# How to modify external SVG loded as object in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, d3.js

I have a working example of modifying elements of external SVG image using D3.js, but can't achieve similar functionality in jQuery.

Got this SVG:

```
<svg stroke="#000" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path id="drop1" d="M21 14.7C21 18.1794 19.0438 21 15.5 21C11.9562 21 10 18.1794 10 14.7C10 11.2206 15.5 3 15.5 3C15.5 3 21 11.2206 21 14.7Z" />
  <path id="drop2" d="M8 8.2C8 9.7464 7.11083 11 5.5 11C3.88917 11 3 9.7464 3 8.2C3 6.6536 5.5 3 5.5 3C5.5 3 8 6.6536 8 8.2Z" />
</svg>
```

load it as object:

```
<object onload="colorize()" id="svg" type="image/svg+xml" data="image.svg"></object>
```

and process it when loaded:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function colorize() {
    var drops = d3.select(document.getElementById("svg").contentDocument);
    if(drops.empty()) {
      setTimeout(colorize, 100);
    } else {
      drops.select("#drop1").attr("fill", "#f00");
      drops.select("#drop2").style("visibility", "hidden");
    }
  }
</script>
```

The above works fine. I'd like to do the same without D3.js, possibly using jQuery.

So far I can't even get the desired element:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function colorize() {
    $("#svg #drop1")
    ...
  }
</script>
```

I can't use inline SVG. Also don't want to put any JS inside the SVG file.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `d3.select(document.getElementById("svg").contentDocument)` selects _inside the document that is referenced by `<object>`_, whereas your jQuery selector tries to find the `<path>` element with the ID `drop1` inside the _current_ document.

Comment: be careful with jquery because append does not work with SVG

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need jquery or d3:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <object onload="colorize()" id="svg" type="image/svg+xml" data="image.svg"></object>
    <script>
      function colorize() {
        const drops = document.getElementById('svg');
        if (drops && 
            drops.contentDocument && 
            drops.contentDocument.children) {          
          const svg = drops.contentDocument.children[0];
          svg.getElementById('drop1').setAttribute('fill', '#f00');
          svg.getElementById('drop2').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Running [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/MZ35EyPTwbaNqyHh?preview).